# Rotate about a point or an axis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, vectors, rotations

1. English is not my native language. Why math text uses the preposition "about" while referring rotation in the context of a point, an axis or a plane? Is not the preposition "around" or "on" more natural to use in this context?
2. Is matrix multiplication of NON-square matrix and identity matrix commutative?
3. Scale applies along an axis. For example, if you scale along x-axis, the horizontal length of the shape will increase/decrease in 2D. Why the author of the following para (whole para is pasted below to clear the context) is saying that it **is applied about the perpendicular axis**? Also, why did he use the preposition "about" here?

> **Scaling along the Cardinal Axes**
> The simplest scale operation applies a separate scale factor along each cardinal axis. The scale along an axis **is applied about the perpendicular axis** (in 2D) or plane (in 3D). If the scale factors for all axes are equal, then the scale is uniform; otherwise, it is nonuniform.

Please help if you can answer any one of the three questions.

Thanks.

Comment: Obviously, around and about are synonyms in this context. You can't swap a rectangular and a square matrix in a product for obvious dimension compatibility reason.

Comment: Thanks. Can we call following multiplication commutative: IA=AI where A is rectangle matrix and I is a square matrix and dimension compatibility requirement is met?

Comment: Please given an example of $A$ that would make this comparison possible.

Comment: A (2x3): A1 (first row) = [1 2 3] A2 = [4 5 6]. I (3x3) identity. AI=A. I (2x2) then IA=A. Can we say it commutative even if dimension of I is different is both cases?

Comment: Is $I$ $2\times2$ or $3\times3$ ?

Comment: I is 2 x 2 for IA and 3 x 3 for AI.

Comment: Come on, this is nonsense, $I\ne I$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"around" is pretty common too; this is more a question for the English language stacks, but I know that "about" was more commonly used in the past the way "around" is now; see for instance this passage from Shakespeare's Macbeth.

> O well done! I commend your pains;
>
> And every one shall share i' the gains;
>
> And now **about the cauldron sing,**
>
> Live elves and fairies **in a ring,**
>
> Enchanting all that you put in.

---

A matrix that isn't square can only be multiplied on both sides by *another matrix that isn't square*: a $2\times3$ matrix can only be multiplied on both sides by a $3\times2$ matrix.  The results of these two multiplications are both square matrices, of different sizes: if $A$ is $2\times3$ and $B$ is $3\times2$, then $C = AB$ is a $2\times2$ matrix, and $D = BA$ is a $3\times3$ matrix.  Because they are different sizes, $C$ and $D$ are obviously not equal; because they are not square, neither $A$ nor $B$ can be an identity matrix.

---

The final passage is ... not how I would put things, but I think what he means is - a scaling along a particular axis fixes its perpendicular: in 2 dimensions, a scaling along one axis leaves a line perpendicular to the axis unchanged, and in 3 dimensions it similarly leaves a plane perpendicular to the axis unchanged.  This sense of "about" is shared with rotation, in that in both cases these operations leave the things they are "about" unchanged.

Comment: Excellent answers. It was a treat to read answer of the 3rd question. Thanks. You know better but  as per my knowledge a non-square matrix can be multiplied with a square matrix: AB is possible if  A = 2 x 3 and B is 3 x 3, AB is also possible if A is 2 x 2 and B is 2 x 3. Please clarify why non-square matrix can not be multiplied with a square matrix on either side?

Comment: Those two matrices, the 2x2, and 3x3, are *different matrices*, even if they're both technically identity matrices.